# "OutputPath property is not set" error occurs only when calling MSBuild in CCNET

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config, msbuild-4.0

I've made an MSBuild project that simply does an msbuild task with our solution file as parameter. I've defined a BeforeBuild target where I set some properties, and a Build target that executes the msbuild task.

I've confirmed that no errors occured when building the msbuild script in the command line console. However, when I use it in the msbuild task in my CCNET project, I keep getting the following error:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets
>   (483,9): error: The OutputPath
>   property is not set for project
>   'MyProject.msbuild'.  Please check to
>   make sure that you have specified a
>   valid combination of Configuration and
>   Platform for this project. 
>   Configuration='Debug' 
>   Platform='AnyCPU'.  You may be seeing
>   this message because you are trying to
>   build a project without a solution
>   file, and have specified a non-default
>   Configuration or Platform that doesn't
>   exist for this project.

I checked the build log and it seems that the error occurs during _CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform. It wasn't even able to continue to my Build task! Since the script is only intended to build the solution under Debug/Release and AnyCPU as platform, I tried to add the following lines to my msbuild project:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' ==  'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
  <OutputPath>.\bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' ==  'Release|AnyCPU' ">
  <OutputPath>.\bin\Release\</OutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I could still build the project without errors in the command line, but CCNET is returning the same error mentioned above.

I don't understand why CCNET keeps getting the error, and I don't know what else to try.

Please help.

Comment: Does this help? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brandonwerner/archive/2010/03/14/the-nasty-visual-studio-platform-mcd-error-in-visual-studio-2010-rc.aspx

Comment: Can you post the msbuild task used inside CC.NET?

Answer (score 10):

I found I had a similar situation (but using TeamCity as my CI environment).  In my particular case, the project was a Command Line application.  To solve it, I had to manually edit my project file.

Find these lines:

```
<Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
<Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
```

Change the second line to:

```
<Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
```

The find the other platform-specific lines in the project file and change them.  Example:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
```

becomes:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
```

My suspicion is our build servers are 64-bit and the Console Application project type in Studio won't let you make the project fit an AnyCPU platform...

After these changes, TeamCity had no problem with my build script.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Without this answer, I highly doubt I would have ever been able to trace this down.

Comment: If anyone else comes across this the first lines belong in the initial Property Group and in my case the platform line was missing altogether.  Adding it fixed the issue with TeamCity

Answer (score 3):

The answer from David helped me. But later I found the actual source of the issue for my computer. The **PLATFORM** environment variable is added on HP machines and does impact a number of different scenarios with Visual Studio.

Go into Environment Variables-> System Variables and remove the "PLATFORM" from the list.

See additional details here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2010/03/24/outputpath-property-is-not-set-for-project-error-when-building-a-windows-azure-cloud-service-in-vs-2010.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the additional information.  That must have been a real bugger to solve!

Comment: in my case it was really just all about putting more property groups with the Platform, sometimes people customize it (put another name like `MyAcceptance`) and then cruise control fires this error. So you have to add this name also to the source code of the csproj